# Git push using VS code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I checked out the code from the master branch for my new requirement implementation.
After the checkout, I created another branch as git new branch "feature_branch".

But after making changes, I staged all the changes and committed them into the branch (currently, it is not pushed into the remote branch yet).

And when I was trying to push into the remote feature branch (considering that feature branch will be created in remote), but it is trying to push into master. Why, it should not push my feature branch code into the master one. Once I will push the code into the feature branch, then someone can review and merge it into the master.

While push I am getting this pop up:
[image]

The current snapshot of all branches I have, the red one is the one feature branch which I wanted to push into remote as is, the yellow one is the other branches:
[image]

Please correct me if I am doing something wrong here.
I am using Visual Studio Code to do everything.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you created `feature_branch` by `git checkout -b feature_branch origin/master`. If so, `feature_branch` tracks `master` from `origin`. When you run `git push` or push via VS code, it's equivalent to `git push origin feature_branch:master`.

Run `git config branch.feature_branch.merge`. If it returns `refs/heads/master`, run `git config branch.feature_branch.merge refs/heads/feature_branch` and push again.

If it doesn't work, try `git push origin -u feature_branch:refs/heads/feature_branch` in the command line.

Comment: Yes, you are right I check out my feature branch from master only which is first half, but when I ran second half for git config nothing appears on the screen, I also tried after that as well but no luck, I updated my question with a response I am getting whiling doing push.

Comment: @IndrajeetGour How about `git push origin -u feature_branch:refs/heads/feature_branch`?

Comment: I tied it, but it was throwing me an error : "error: src refspec feature_branch does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to master one"

Comment: @IndrajeetGour replace `feature_branch` with the real name of your feature_branch.

Comment: Yes, I did replace with my feature branch. Added screenshot for my available branches as well in main question.

Comment: @ ElpieKay do you know what to do now ?? I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @IndrajeetGour I don't know where your remote repository is hosted. Do you have the permission to create a branch in the remote repository?

Answer (score 0):

1. checkout the feature branche using git checkout feature_branch.
2. verify that your commits are there with git log.
3. push your feature branch to server with git push -u origin feature_branch.